# How do I get involved in writing for video games?

Tags: videogame, script, getting-started

Many video games have deep storylines. This has been the case since the early text adventures where creative writing was all that existed to keep a player engaged in the game. I believe that some stories are better served by this interactive medium rather than say a novelization or a movie script and I'd love to give it a try, but without having any contacts in that industry or real experience working in that medium, I was wondering what it takes to get started? Find or start an open source game project? Send some kind of treatment to an established game publisher or developer?

Comment: Here are some resources you might be interested in: [Writing for the Gaming Industry](http://www.writing-world.com/freelance/games.shtml) [The Ultimate Guide to Video Game Writing and Design](http://www.amazon.com/Ultimate-Guide-Video-Writing-Design/dp/158065066X)

Comment: Conveniently, this was just addressed in a post at Tor.com: [Breaking Into Video Game Writing](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2010/12/breaking-into-video-game-writing)

Answer (score 8):

My first advice is -- don't.  There's an attitude in the gaming industry that working on games is so cool they shouldn't have to pay you a fair wage.  Working conditions in the game industry tend to lag behind other sectors.  Salaries for graphic artists and coders in the game industry are about 1/3 of what those same people would make in any other sector, and I suspect it is the same for writers.

If you must get into the game industry, though, find a company with a history of treating its people fairly, and that use an open-source engine under their games.  The business argument for a company to use an open-source engine is persuasive, but for you as a writer the biggest difference is in corporate culture and willingness to give you a fair shake.

Once you've figured out who you want to work with, put together a proposal, send it in, and cross your fingers.

Comment: This guy is totally right. We'd never hire a writer and pay them a real wage. Plus, writing for the game is the fun part, and developers will do that for free. Sad but true.

Comment: I have to agree with @John ... If you honestly wanted to write for video games, you're better as a developer/designer, since writers are rarely hired for more than a short contract.

Answer (score 3):

Bioware had a [contest](http://www.bioware.com/biozone/articles/2005_11_30_WritingContest/) several years ago to hire a writer.  Certainly not an appealing way to go about applying for a job, but that contest did leave behind some potentially useful tips for what sort of writing game companies might be looking for, eg:

> Some additional guidelines to keep in
>   mind:
>
> - Dialogue should be no longer than 2-3    lines at a time.
> - The dialogue must be    fun, easy to read, and not overly    verbose.
> - We will also be judging the    structure of your dialogue. Does the
>     dialogue flow logically? Does the player feel in control of the conversation?
> - Avoid dialogue where    the player has very little    interaction. The
>     player should feel    that he is
>     talking to an NPC, not    being talked
>     at.
> - Avoid modern    sounding dialogue. Do not use modern    anachronisms or
>     slang. Fantasy    characters shouldn't
>     sound like they    come from the 21st
>     century.
> - Make the    first character interesting. The    first character
>     the player talks to    sets the tone
>     for the entire module.

Creating a Neverwinter Nights module would definitely be something you could do in order to get a feel for the flow of writing if you want to get involved in writing for *RPGs*.